# ElasticBean stalk Linux 2 ProcFile running error

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

I have a procFile on Linux1 that executes a script and sets up environment variables for a java process.

```
web: sh /var/app/current/scripts/sample.sh
```

The `sample.sh` file is something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
logs=/var/tmp/logs; export logs
ps -ef|grep [t]estProcess
if[[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "process started"
  exit 1
fi

exec java -Dservice.name=testProcess com.shakeout.testProcess
```

Upon migration to Linux 2, the proc file is failing to execute any of the system processes either `ps -ef` or `exec java`.

I have checked that it was able to display the `PATH` when I have put `echo $PATH`.

Anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You invoke the script with `sh /var/app/current/scripts/sample.sh`. On your old Linux distribution, it is possible `/bin/sh` pointed to `/bin/bash`, and now on your new Linux distribution, `/bin/sh` may not point to `/bin/bash`. Note that `[[` is not valid in POSIX `sh`.

You should change your Procfile to use `web: bash /var/app/current/scripts/sample.sh`.